# Error Running MVC2 application in IIS on .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, .net-4.0

I recently installed the RTM version of 4.0. I now receive an error when running MVC2 websites in a .net 4 app pool. The error is "User is not available in this context." All works fine on .net 2.0 app pools or if I run the app within the VS10 web server. The error only occurs in IIS on .net 4.0. To verify that it was not something specific to my app, I created a new MVC test app from the VS template and even that app encounters this error. My next step is to reinstall .net 4.0.

Has anyone else seen this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the framework fixed this.